# Why does DOMParser alter whitespace?

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

Why does the following use of DOMParser result in HTML different than the HTML used as input? It removes the whitespace between the DOCTYPE and the top-level element, removes the whitespace between the document element and `head`, and adds a newline before `</body>`.

I have tested this in Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari; I also ran the analogous code with [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) and got exactly the same results. So I'm pretty sure it's not a bug. My current theory is that this is caused by some sort of esoteric parsing rule from a specification somewhere. But there could be other things I misunderstand.

```js
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Hello, World!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`;

const setText = function(id,string) {
  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));
};

const documentToString = function(d) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(d.childNodes).map(function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE) return node.outerHTML;
    if (node.nodeType == node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE) return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
    throw new TypeError("" + node);
  }).join("");
};

setText("raw", html);
var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html,"text/html");
setText("parsed", parsed.documentElement.outerHTML);
setText("converted", documentToString(parsed));
setText("xmlserializer", new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(parsed));
```

```css
#raw, #parsed, #converted, #xmlserializer { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
h1 { font-size: 110%; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Raw string</h1>
<div id="raw"></div>
<h1>Parsed top-level element</h1>
<div id="parsed"></div>
<h1>Using a document-to-string converter</h1>
<div id="converted"></div>
<h1>From XMLSerializer</h1>
<div id="xmlserializer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Whitespace between tags is not syntactically significant. A million spaces are the same as one space.

Comment: Difference between significant and insignificant whitespace, http://usingxml.com/Basics/XmlSpace

Comment: That is true, but there are plenty of cases where one would want to preserve formatting.

Comment: _“but there are plenty of cases where one would want to preserve formatting”_ - well, then one would have to do one’s operations on a text level, and not a DOM level :-)

Comment: XML DOM parsers typically preserve whitespace exactly, as whitespace-only text nodes between the other nodes. Parsing a document and then serializing it will return the same string. In any case, why is the parser *inserting* whitespace (at the end of the document body)?

Comment: I have typically used parsers like the JAXP parser included with the Java Development Kit and other parsers like Xerces. All preserve whitespace exactly when requested.

Comment: And, to folks saying "whitespace is insignificant," it's not like the parser is removing whitespace. It's mostly preserving it, but in two specific places, every single implementation is removing a whitespace-only text node in the same place, and every single implementation is inserting a whitespace-only text node in the same place.

Comment: I'd like to know what problem this is having, I mean you've shown us in code "exhibit a" and I can see what you mean about how the serialization of the dom looks different to a human reader, but I'd like to know what the concern is.

Comment: Let's say I want to process someone's source code (and emit new source code) without altering the other parts, for example, @Scuzzy ...

Comment: Another use-case: Pasting rich-text. Depending on what browser the text is copied from, the clipboard contents in HTML form may be different (Firefox doesn't put wrapping <span>s around unwrapped text nodes like other browsers do, for example). Throw that through `DOMParser.parseFromString()`, and random newlines now show up before/after this text (since it's a direct child of the body). This means pasting inconsistent text from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's what [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing) ask to do.

HTML is not XML, and a lot of transformations will happen. For instance, you may not realize, but your very StackSnippet contains a duplicate `<body>` tag, because the HTML section is actually wrapped in such a tag by the snippet's script. The duplicate is ignored at document parsing.

```js
console.log('how many bodies?', document.querySelectorAll('body').length);
```

```html
<body><body><body></body></body></body>
```

Similar transformations happen to TextNodes.

And yes, it's not a `DOMParser` thing, it's really an HTML DOM parsing one, you have the same behavior at document parsing:

```js
frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Hello, World!
    </div>
    <script>      parent.postMessage(document.documentElement.outerHTML, "*");
    <\/script>
  </body>
</html>`], {type: 'text/html'}));

onmessage = e => console.log(e.data);
```

```html
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

Now, if you wish to retrieve the exact same string, then parse it as XML instead:

```js
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Hello, World!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`;

const setText = function(id,string) {
  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));
};

const documentToString = function(d) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(d.childNodes).map(function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE) return node.outerHTML;
    if (node.nodeType == node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE) return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
    throw new TypeError("" + node);
  }).join("");
};

setText("raw", html);
var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html,"text/xml");
setText("parsed", parsed.documentElement.outerHTML);
setText("converted", documentToString(parsed));
setText("xmlserializer", new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(parsed));
```

```css
#raw, #parsed, #converted, #xmlserializer { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
h1 { font-size: 110%; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<h1>Raw string</h1>
<div id="raw"></div>
<h1>Parsed top-level element</h1>
<div id="parsed"></div>
<h1>Using a document-to-string converter</h1>
<div id="converted"></div>
<h1>From XMLSerializer</h1>
<div id="xmlserializer"></div>
```

Comment: Lots of valid HTML documents are not valid (or well-formed) XML, so this isn't really an option. I appreciate the link to the specification, but it is unclear to me exactly which parsing rules in that specification are leading to 1. removing the whitespace between DOCTYPE and html, 2. removing the whitespace between html and head, 3. adding a newline at the end of body, 4. preserving all the other whitespace, in every single implementation. There must be rules or they wouldn't all be behaving in the same highly specific way.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't go through all your document quoting the relevant specs everywhere ;-) For the <DOCTYPE><html> one, [it's here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#after-doctype-name-state), 1st case "**U+0020 SPACE**
    Ignore the character." Also, I don't get your point about html are not valid XML. Of course they all aren't, that's why HTML is way more laxist in its parsing rules than is XML. However that also means that the DOM you have is not the markup you gave, and you can't retrieve this markup from the DOM.

Comment: Sorry my link for !DOCTYPE><html was actually wrong. [At tokenization](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#after-doctype-name-state), the `>` at the end of  `<!DOCTYPE>` sends us to the [data state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#data-state) where the space character is just emitted. It's at insertion that it will get ignored, after the doctype has been added, we enter the [before-html-insertion-mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-before-html-insertion-mode) and here the third bullet tells us to ignore that space character token.