# DOMParser() removes spaces

Tags: html, dom

Simple code:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const foo = parser.parseFromString(<p>      Foo</p>, 'text/html');
console.log(foo);
```

gives me this

[image: Result from parseFromString]

Where have all the empty spaces in front of Foo gone?

Comment: HTML ignores more than 2 white spaces, why do you care about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does DOMParser alter whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394776/why-does-domparser-alter-whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your output, but I do get an output with all spaces retained using

```
console.log(foo.documentElement)
```